# how to count on unique records of public_activity actions in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am using public_activity gem.

```
@num = PublicActivity::Activity.where(owner_id: current_user.id, key: "micropost.read").count
```

This would show correctly how many times a current_user has read on all microposts. However, if current_user has read on the same micropost muliple times, it would count those number too. But I don't want that. If a current_user has read the same micropost multiple times, I'd like to be counted as only one time.

I have tried

```
@num = PublicActivity::Activity.where(owner_id: current_user.id, key: "micropost.read").distinct.count
```

it did not show any error messages, but it did not work.

I have tried

```
@num = PublicActivity::Activity.distinct.where(owner_id: current_user.id, key: "micropost.read").count
```

it did not work.

What is correct syntax for getting this done? Thanks in advance!

Ruby 2.3.1, rails 5.0.0.1

Comment: As you are using where(:owner_id => ....),you will always get all counts for that user...

Comment: you may use @num.include?(@current_user) to check and just show first record using @num.first...hope it helps

Comment: Yes, I have already got all counts by current_user. however, I'd like to get distinct counts by current_user. current_user might read a micropost multiple times, I want that to be counted as 1 read instead of multiple reads. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try querying the same using trackable_id. I'am using pluck(:id) so that my querying becomes easy since it gives me an array of id's.

```
@num = PublicActivity::Activity.where(owner_id: current_user.id, key: "micropost.read", trackable_id: Micropost.pluck(:id)).distinct.count
```

Comment: I can see where you come from. Unfortunately it did not work in my case. No error message neither.